# JSTL c:foreach not iterating through the collection object

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jstl, el

I was previously using ui.repeat to iterate over a collection and create some primefaces
datatables.However, at that time I was not able to set dynamic ids to the datatables.So after doing some research I thought of changing it to c:foreach and try.However,now my datatables are not getting generated because I believe at build time when the c:forach runs,the collection is empty.
I am using jstl 1.2.
I tried the following after populating the list.

```
    HttpServletRequest origRequest=(HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance        ().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    origRequest.setAttribute("dataList",dataList);
```

Then in my xhtml I tried this: items="${dataList}"
But nothing seems to be working.Please help.

EDIT: Funcational Requirement

I will generate multiple data tables at runtime using ui:repeat/p:datalist/c:foreach etc.
Then from my backend I want to have access to each of these datatables because I want to write them in a pdf file using the primefaes dataexporter.For this purpose I wanted to assign dynamic Ids to the datatables.But I am not able to make it work.

Comment: Please show how you create these primefaces datatables.

Comment: After changing the jstl namespace to xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" now it is going inside the loop.But still the table is not getting created.This is how I am creating the tables <c:forEach var="loopObject" items="#{bean.dataList}" varStatus="loop" >
          
<p:dataTable id="table_#{loop.index}" var="object" value="#{loopObject.value}">            
<p:column>
<f:facet name="header">  
<h:outputText value="SomeHeader" />  
 </f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{object.someValue}" />
</p:column>
</p:dataTable> The dataList items is of type List<Entry<String, List<someVO>>>

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> *After changing the jstl namespace to xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"; now it is going inside the loop*

This suggests that you're *actually* using JSTL 1.0, not JSTL 1.1/1.2, in contrary to what you said in the question. In other words, your runtime classpath is a mess. A common starter's mistake in this case is that they have arbitrary downloaded a `standard.jar` file becasue something didn't work in JSTL and they saw it mentioned somewhere in a completely outdated or poor resource (I sincerely hope that you have among others roseindia.net in your lifetime internet blacklist, right?). You should **not** have this file when using JSTL 1.2.

Carefully read the versions overview and installation instructions in [our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) for the right download links and the right approach.

Comment: Thanx for for inputs balusC.I rechecked my classpath and removed the standard.jar form there.This is my web.xml "<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">".I have seen examples put by you in which you are successfully able to assign dynamic ids to the variables but for some reason it is evaluating to null always for me.Plz help.

Comment: I will edit the question to indicate my functional requiremets.Please guide me if my approach is wrong.